# How to clean folder leftovers of the apps that are no longer in use?

Tags: filesystem

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and I'd like to know are there possibilities to clean folder leftovers of the apps that I don't use anymore and not planning to again. 
For example in /home when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> folders appear and some of them belong to apps that I don't use anymore and I have to manually to search for them and delete each by one. 
So I wonder are there any commands I can use in Terminal to clean those leftovers, if they are?

Comment: thanks @Takkat for the link it seems similar to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

If that doesn't work try:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean
```

**When uninstalling Remove vs Purge.**

`sudo apt-get remove <package-name>` the configuration files are not removed.

`sudo apt-get purge <package-name>` Might be more suitable for what it is that you are looking to do. As this will also purge the configuration files.

**EDIT: This does not remove hidden folders.** 
Those will need to be removed manually as suggested by @Takkat and @Oli here:

( [How can I detect and delete all lost configuration folders?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24201/how-can-i-detect-and-delete-all-lost-configuration-folders))

Comment: Thanx but I use those commands frequently and it didn't seem to clean those folders or I didn't notice. I will try to check it.

Comment: Also the above comment by by @Takkat is very relevant as in will probably be the only approach at the moment.